# Unable to find an option to install CentOS 6.4 (64bit) in command line (linux text) for Asterisk

Tags: centos, asterisk

I am trying to learn Asterisk, so I downloaded the latest CentOS 6.4 (64bit) to install on VMWare Workstation 9.
When I started the installation it is not giving any screen to start the installation in command line mode, like it did with CentOS 5.5 (like type linux text command).
The reason I want to install it in CLI is that I do not know Linux at all except a few commands and CLI gives option to uncheck GENOME, KDE, Server and more during installation. I really do not know what options to select in GUI while installing from the customization menu (like what all components to install). Is there any way to do it?

I am also wondering if the MINIMAL install feature on CentOS 6.4 (64bit) is same as CentOS 5.5 (32bit), where if we start installation with "linux text" command and unselect every package including KDE, GENOME, SERVER and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to eradicate the GUI during the installation; in fact, when I did the installation, I couldn't find any option to install *without* the CLI. So I ended up just setting the machine to *boot* in CLI mode.  This is what I did on my Centos 6.2:

Set bootlevel to 3, which will boot to the CLI instead of the GUI.

http://www.linux-archive.org/centos/144862-boot-centos-5-command-line.html

Edit the `/etc/inittab` file and change the line that says:

`id:5:initdefault:`  to  `id:3:initdefault:`